# Gmail "Web login required"

Tags: gmail, pop3, webmail

I am constantly getting "web login required" when accessing Gmail using POP from the email application. I know what should be causing it but I am unable to figure out why it won't go away. Here is what I tried:

- enabled "Less secure apps" to ensure it can use the regular username/password (https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)
- checked if "2-step verification" is disabled and it is disabled so this should not cause issues (https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1064203?hl=en)
- went to "Sign in & security" and clicked on every item displayed about suspicious activity and clicked "yes, it was me" button
- checked if POP support is enabled in Gmail webmail interface and it is
- did a "display unlock captcha" to supposedly unlock (https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

But it still persistently shows "web login required". Did I miss anything else? Is there a way to "reset" the account so the web login required goes away?

Comment: Have you tried creating an app-specific password? That way your email app can use a one-time use password and you can keep the more secure password and 2-factor settings applied to your account.

Comment: @music2myear I did, enabled 2-step verification and created app-specific password (and replaced regular password in email app, with the app-specific password) and the only result was again the very same "web login required". Nuts!

Comment: What email application? Your question is still lacking relevant information. Please edit it to improve the question and our ability to answer it.

Comment: It is not relevant for the question but it is Outlook Express. The question applies to any POP client as POP is standardized protocol.

Comment: Same problem with Thunderbird.

Comment: One possibility is if you have several gmail accounts. If one of them is actually listed as connected in your web browser, then it looks like it prevents the "display unlock captcha" to work correctly.

Comment: Display unlock captcha worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and ultimately it was fixed by the *Less secure apps* setting.  Which I know you already tried to set.  It didn't take for me either when I set it via this link:

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

When I visited this page, scrolled to the bottom, it was still disabled, and enabling it there corrected the issue.

https://myaccount.google.com/security

Also, make sure you use your full email address as the username.

Comment: Just an added step to the 'less secure apps' setting: if the error message POP3 says "Web login required", just log out of the account and log in again.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting temporary Internet files under Tools/Delete Browsing History in Internet Explorer, especially if you've just changed the ISP you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was also 'Less secure apps setting'.
It is odd, but I had to turn it off and on again and it is working now...